# how can find a part of program in an application

Tags: serial-port, reverse-engineering, forgot-password, password-hash

I have an external device ,the device has a itself application which connect to pc with rs-232 ,there is a password when i want connect to it for monitor or maintenance ,the program opend a window and ask the password, i havent it , now i want wirte a scan program for test all possible password and find it how could i do it?
there are three method to reach this goal: 1- write an application into scan all possible passwords :
1- write an application into test one by one possible password that at first step must be know how do work the device's application into send and recive data on rs-232 port.or finde application's part which we enter password and the password be transfered to rs-232. ofcourse it seem more easy than others but i dont have enough experince to manage it so pleas help to me

2- be monitor the port by a program such as ollydebug and find the password that it is too hard because the prosece are too complex and we will face to many jump in body of program and in additon to there are hex code ...

3- just write a program to join to device's application and enter and test all possible passwords when the password's window is opened

so whats your suggestion? pleas help me thanks note1 : password's characters are 6 digit :0-9a-z not2:just a program which check out all possible password

Comment: use dictionary method which is quite popular & used

Comment: @ Thiru Shetty hi... sorry? whats your  mean?